# How to replace a capability-value in the Selenium Grid before passing to a node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

[image: Can a Selenium Grid change the DesiredCaps of the SeleniumClient?]

**Is their a way to change the values of the Capabilities in the Selenium Grid?**

I am already extending the `org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher` in a java class to validate some values. Need a way to replace them as well before passing to the Nodes?

Comment: Even if such a way exists, you will allocate a Chrome v30 to a client which requested Chrome v26. Doesnt that break the contract?

Comment: Ummm, that is not exactly the usecase. Actually the user would ask for a "browser code" like give me b2831. Now the hub should replace the b2831 with Google Chrome v31

Comment: In that case you will be having a mapping, right?

Comment: @Shubhasmit Yes, i will have a Mapping, but only on the Machine where SeleniumGrid is present.

Comment: hub can not do that on it's own, you have to build a logic to do that.

Comment: Not sure this is even a valid question. Sure: the Grid has default values. BUT: every session thread you start first begins with its own Capabilities object that is part of the RemoteWebDriver instance , which I assume overrides the Node defaults?  Of course the node that is selected by the grid will match the browser name and version you selected but I would guess that the other capabilities should override any of the other default options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your on custom proxy to do so.
In the custom proxy you need to extend the following class:
**org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy**
and override **beforeSession** function which has **TestSession** object as a parameter, from where you can get the capabilities.
While registering your node you need to specify the new proxy and start the hub with new custom proxy.